# scrapy crawl filename -O out.json is ok but in file out.json , price is null

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, null

```
import scrapy


class Divar(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Divar'
    start_urls = [
        'https://divar.ir/s/fuman/buy-old-house?user_type=personal&non-negotiable=true']

    def parse(self, response):
        for land in response.css('div.kt-post-card__body'):
            yield {
                'name': land.css('div.kt-post-card__title::text').get(),
                'price': land.css('div.kt-post-card__description::text').get(),
            }
```

This is a sample in json file that's empty :
{"name": "زمین 156 مترمربع مسکونی،تجاری", "price": []}

price is null. However in cmd when i enter scrapy crawl Divar -O Divar.json, price is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found it :)

instead of get you must write extract.

for example:

```
'name': land.css('div.kt-post-card__title::text').extract()
```

Comment: `extract()` is same as `getall()` and `extract_first()` is same as `get()`. The `extract()` functions are not recommended any more. So in this case, you should be using `getall()`. See [this link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#old-extraction-api)

Comment: Thank you. `getall()` works.